# Determine if column exists in table and run code if so

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to loop through my tables and if a column name exists then delete all records within that table.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  select *
  from information_schema.columns
  order by table_name, ordinal_position

  IF EXISTS(
    select 'CorporationId'
    from information_schema.columns
    where TABLE_NAME = @tn
  )
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Stored procedure already exists';
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat('DELETE FROM ', @tn, ' WHERE CorporationId = @CorporationId');
    print @sql;
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@CorporationId uniqueidentifier', @CorporationId=@CorporationId;
  END;
```

At this point, I'm just getting a bunch of CorporationId and I'm not returning that it exists. How do I determine if the column exists and run code if it does?

Comment: Start by posting complete code that runs without syntax errors if possible. You have variables that are not declared or assigned. You print the **single** dynamic sql statement you generate - so what does it contain? Is that statement correct? What does it do when you execute it?

Comment: `PRINT 'Stored procedure already exists';` And this is just wrong. You have enough rep to be writing better code than this.

Answer (score 3):

You ca use below code:

```
IF EXISTS(
    select *
    from information_schema.columns
    where TABLE_NAME = @tn AND COLUMN_NAME = N'CorporationId'
  )
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Stored procedure already exists';
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat('DELETE FROM ', @tn, ' WHERE CorporationId = @CorporationId');
    print @sql;
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@CorporationId uniqueidentifier', @CorporationId=@CorporationId;
  END;
```